# Random forest com acurácia muito alta

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn

Estou trabalhando com [este dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction/kernels?sortBy=relevance&group=everyone&search=gradient&page=1&pageSize=20&datasetId=128) e apliquei random forest para criar um modelo de previsão de preços, porém a acurácia do modelo está dando alta demais, por isso estou desconfiando se tem algo errado. Aparentemente train e test estão diferentes, então não era para dar uma acurácia tão alta... tem algum erro?

print(score2) e 
print(accu2):

> 0.9981901132115226
>
> [0.99086244 0.99562853 0.99551529 0.9988478  0.99997931]

```
#Random forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor,AdaBoostRegressor,ExtraTreesRegressor,GradientBoostingRegressor,BaggingRegressor
rf = RandomForestRegressor()

#conjunto sem data nem id
df2 = df.drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)

#tira o price do df2 e coloca em x
x = df2.drop(['price'], axis=1)
#coloca em y apenas o price
y = df2['price']

x_train, x_test = train_test_split(x,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(x_train.count())
print(x_test.count())

print(x_train.head(2))
print(x_test.head(2))


rf.fit(x_train,y_train)

score2 = rf.score(x_test,y_test)
accu2 = cross_val_score(rf,x_train,y_train,cv=5)

print("____ Random Forest Regressor____\n")
print(score2)
print(accu2)
```

Também está assim quando aplico Gradient Boosting Regressor

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score


#conjunto sem data nem id
df2 = df.drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)

#tira o price do df2 e coloca em x
x = df2.drop(['price'], axis=1)
#coloca em y apenas o price
y = df2['price']

#x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y ,test_size=0.2)


gb = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
gb.fit(x_train,y_train)

score4 = gb.score(x_test,y_test)
pred = gb.predict(x_test)
exp_est = explained_variance_score(pred, y_test)

print("exp_est: ") 
print(exp_est)

#accu4 = cross_val_score(gb,x_train,y_train,cv=5)
print("____ Gradient Boosting Regressor____\n")
print(score4)
print(accu4)
```

> 0.998862149174232
>
> [0.99741288 0.9989814  0.99979751 0.99906217 0.9999443 ]

Comment: Tem certeza que voce nao faz nenhum alteração no dataset? Eu [criei um notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/begnini/test-so-343368-predicao-muito-alta) no kaggle com seu código e a acurácia dá bem abaixo do que voce esta postando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leila, estranhamente não consegui gerar os mesmos valores de acurácia e score que você, com o mesmo código e *dataset* (baixei o *dataset* do Kaggle).

Para o *dataset* encontrei os seguintes valores de score e acc:

> 0.8388415464783893
>
> [0.85563895 0.86273709 0.8589165  0.87741256 0.85294125]

Veja se você não está forçando o *overtraining*, reaproveitando "materiais" de outros treinamentos realizados anteriormente no mesmo código... (estou partindo do princípio de que você não alterou o *dataset* da Kaggle, mas esse é um ponto a observar).

Abaixo o código completo que eu utilizei (tomei a liberdade de remover as referências não utilizadas):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')

#conjunto sem data nem id
df2 = df.drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)

#tira o price do df2 e coloca em x
x = df2.drop(['price'], axis=1)
#coloca em y apenas o price
y = df2['price']

x_train, x_test = train_test_split(x,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(x_train.count())
print(x_test.count())

print(x_train.head(2))
print(x_test.head(2))

rf.fit(x_train,y_train)

score2 = rf.score(x_test,y_test)
accu2 = cross_val_score(rf,x_train,y_train,cv=5)

print("____ Random Forest Regressor____\n")
print(score2)
print(accu2)
```